# Random Color Generation of my Choice

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

Hey guys :) I am using Swift and Spritkit in Xcode 7. At the moment I am using this code to generate a random color at it is working fine.

```
func random() -> CGFloat {
return CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(100))/100
}

func niceRandomColor() -> UIColor {

return UIColor(hue: random(), saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

However, I want to generate just 2 random colors of my choice using RBG.

```
(red: ?/255, green: ?/255, blue: ?/255, alpha: 1)
```

How can I generate random colors of my choice?

Cheers!

Comment: HI, 'random colors'  and  'of my choice' are contradictory. Will you please explain a bit more about what exactly you want by 'my choice' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use an enum to describe the available Colors for your case.

Something like this:

```
enum Color {
    case ColorOne
    case ColorTwo

    private var color: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .ColorOne: return UIColor(red: 1/255, green: 2/255, blue: 3/255, alpha: 1)
        case .ColorTwo: return UIColor(red: 10/255, green: 20/255, blue: 30/255, alpha: 1)
        }
    }

    static var all: [Color] = [.ColorOne, .ColorTwo]

    static var randomColor: UIColor {
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(all.count)))
        return all[randomIndex].color
    }
}

// Then, you'd use it like this:
let random = Color.randomColor
```

Comment: Thanks patchdiaz! Works perfectly! Cheers :)